# What's the simplest way to copy a php array without the first record?

Tags: php, arrays

If you are creating an array, say:

```
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

What's the simplest way to get all the array values apart from the first?

```
$controller = $url[0];

//Pseudo Code
$data       = $url[!0];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using array slice.

```
$data = array_slice($url, 1);
```

Comment: this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$data = $controller;
unset ($data[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_shift](https://www.php.net/array_shift), which is to shift an element off the beginning of array.

```
$controller = array_shift($url);
$data = $url;
```